# how to add a plus sign and milliseconds to a date in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

the date is like `2021-07-23`

the expected output is like this `2021-07-24 00:00:00+08` notice the `+08` ?

I tried like this below, but i am not getting the plus symbol

`s_table.school_date + INTERVAL '1 day'`

any idea how to make that `+08` appear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the time with time zone included.

Try running the following in Postgres and it will return you the datetime with time zone which is after `+` or `-` depending on where you are.

```
SELECT NOW();
```

#### Edit-01:

try the following code:

```
s_table.school_date::timestamptz + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Comment: no, I already gave the sample data that I have. its only year , month, day. I have to output it along with the hour , minutes, seconds plus the plus sign and seconds ..please reread the description in my post. thank you.

Comment: I have to add a 1 day interval, please see the example above

Comment: never mind. .I have solved it like this `(s_table.school_date + INTERVAL '1 day')::timestamptz`

Comment: @sasori that works too or the code I have provided above.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to test it, but have you tried casting that date to a timestampz?

See [this page from postgresql](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/) tutorial on the different timestamp types.

So you could try:

```
(s_table.school_date + INTERVAL '1 day')::timestampz
```

to cast your current value to a timestamp with a timezone.

If the timezone returned is incorrect you can use `SET timezone='America/Los_Angeles'` or find the timezone your current db is using with `SHOW timezone;` You can also see all timezones for your database with `SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names;`.

I got the timezone specific information from [this resource](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/postgresql-set-time-zone-1064).

I would be sure to test out setting the timezone in a transaction first as I'm concerned it would set the timezone for your entire database and that might affect other procedures / queries happening in your database.

I hope this helps! Sorry I couldn't try it out first before sending this information along.

edit: looks like I was a bit slow! Happy you figured it out :)